# Hide who a Google+ post is shared with

Tags: google-plus, privacy

How can I hide who a Google+ post is shared with? Currently, it looks like anyone I share a post with can see who else I have shared the post with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For private posts, that is correct, and an intentional decision. There is no BCC equivalent in Google+ except to create separate posts. This is intentional because the people commenting on the post may expose each other while posting comments.